# Python's in-built class function

Tags: python, function, class

Do you have a good reference on Python's class in-built function? To me, this function needs a bit of picking up. It looks extremely powerful, but I haven't quite got my head around it and am looking for a good guide.

i am speaking about this:

```
class squash():
    def __init___(self, chocolate)
```

i just don't understand them

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Python's class in-built function".

Comment: @BrenBarn i am speaking about creating a class. i dont really understand them. i am looking for something simple

Comment: Do you mean the 3-argument form of the `type` function, which gets called as the default metaclass behind the scenes by a `class` statement?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).  A question like "I don't understand classes" is too broad to be answered.  You should read the tutorial and ask questions that target what specifically you don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

In Python `class` is not a built-in function, it is a compound statement used for creating classes.  This is described in the docs in the following locations:
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

If you are looking for a function to dynamically create a class, you would want the three argument version of the built-in function [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type).

As for a tutorial on how to use classes in Python, the following is pretty good:
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

Answer (score -1):

They are often referred to as magic methods.  Here is a good resource: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.pdf

Comment: What makes you think this is what the question is asking about?

Comment: @BrenBarn Maybe the weird way the question is asked leads to this.

Comment: Hmm, i interpreted it as the methods (class functions) that the interpreter knows about by default.  * calls the `__mul__` or `__rmul__` etc, `str()` uses the `__str__` method etc.  I guess in that sense they could be thought of as "built-in".  I think I was completely wrong in my interpretation though now, after the poster has clarified.